# Is there a Materialize Icon for Follow/Subscribe

Tags: material-design

I can't seem to find a generic Materialize icon that is used for "follow" or Subscribe. On my site a user can follow dif things such as a song, user, or discussion.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a universal button for subscribe in my opinion. I think bookmark icons describe it well, however.

This one's pretty good:

[image]